# Is hand draw animation fading?

Tags: anime-production

[image]

3D animation could be dominating the anime industry as Knights of Sidonia(pictured above)is one of animes first 3d television series.So does this mean hand drawn animation is gradually fading?

Comment: Worth a read: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8273/are-3dcg-based-animes-cheaper-to-produce

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so. 3D Animation is not preferred over the drawn-out 2d. 3D is something totally different than anime & cartoon's drawn-out look. When they do work hand in hand, like in Ghilbi films, that's good.

Japan's method of animating is quite outdated. They are one of the only still using cels. The act of drawing out each frame on a cel (Cels, are material that can be drawn upon & stacked for an animation effect). Then digitized on to computers to be colored & shaded. Sometimes will still see coloring by hand. Mostly for celebration reasons or special occasions e.g: *Little Witch Academia*.

Although that could all just be done on computers, they choose not to do it. I'm assuming transition period would affect everyone "now". Though it would be great for the future.

Comment: If they continue to use the hand drawn method then why don't they do it by they digital means instead of using pencil and paper?

Comment: @user18661 From the specials where they showed Detective Conan being made they did use digital pens and the such, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade but its not widely used,if they can digitally color and shade the character why don't they do it digitally by tablet then using pencil and paper to animate?

Comment: They don't use paper. They use cels. Cels is this type of material. Like I spoke about, above. Cels, are commonly used because they stack upon each other and build frames. Which directions & chief animators can look over quickly. Instead of going towards computers and checking tabs, etc. It is best if they just did all of that on digital format. However, transitions would cost a lot of money & power. As anime is such a volatile media. It`s hard to handle, such a change.